# [Error]How to solve the error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'power_difference'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "power_difference_test_bcl.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "power_difference_test_bcl.py", line 22, in main
    res = power_difference_op(input_x, input_y, input_pow)
  File "power_difference_test_bcl.py", line 12, in power_difference_op
    out = tf.power_difference()
  File "/opt/AICSE-demo-student/env/tensorflow-v1.10/virtualenv_mlu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation_wrapper.py", line 106, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._dw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'power_difference'
```

this message appears when I execute the code below. I do not know how to sovle "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'power_difference'"

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
os.environ['MLU_VISIBLE_DEVICES']="0"
import tensorflow as tf
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
from power_diff_numpy import *

def power_difference_op(input_x, input_y, input_pow):
        with tf.Session() as sess:

                out = tf.power_difference()
                return sess.run(out, feed_dict = {x:input_x, y:input_y, pow:input_pow})

def main():
        value = 256
        input_x = np.random.randn(1,value,value,3)
        input_y = np.random.randn(1,1,1,3)
        input_pow = np.zeros((2))

        start = time.time()
        res = power_difference_op(input_x, input_y, input_pow)
        end = time.time() - start
        print("comput BCL op cost "+ str(end*1000) + "ms" )

        start = time.time()
        output = power_diff_numpy(input_x, input_y,len(input_pow))
        end = time.time()
        res = np.reshape(res,(-1))
        output = np.reshape(output,(-1))
        print("comput op cost "+ str((end-start)*1000) + "ms" )
        err = sum(abs(res - output))/sum(output)
        print("err rate= "+ str(err*100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

please help me if anyone know the solution.

Comment: Show us the output of this code: `import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__file__)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry, i am not sure what do you mean yet. Should I add "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__file__)"?

Comment: Where did you read or find that tf.power_difference exists?

Comment: Actually i am just debugging the code someone else wrote.

Comment: There is no as such `tf.power_difference` API exist in Tensorflow. You can use `tf.math.pow`. For more details have a look at this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/pow